# AWS cognito pre auth lambda trigger

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, eventtrigger

I'm currently working on a user management project and i'm trying to implement a pre authentification lambda trigger in AWS cognito that checks in an external data base the subscription the authenticated user has  and return it .
Can someone help me with an example ? this is my first time working with aws cognito

I tried adding the query that checks the user subscription in the external db but it didn't work .

Answer (score 0):

To use a pre-authentication Lambda trigger in AWS Cognito you need to create a Lambda function and attach it to the [PreAuthentication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cognito-userpool-lambdaconfig.html#cfn-cognito-userpool-lambdaconfig-preauthentication) attribute.

### Example CloudFormation template

```
Resources:
  ExampleUserPool:
    Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPool
    Properties:
      UserPoolName: ExampleUserPool
      LambdaConfig:
        PreAuthentication:
          - LambdaTrigger: true
            LambdaFunctionArn: !GetAtt PreAuthLambdaFunction.Arn

  PreAuthLambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: PreAuthLambdaFunction
      Runtime: nodejs18.x
```

### Example Lambda function

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
  // Extract attributes from the event object
  const { username } = event.request.userAttributes;

  // Check an external data base the subscription the authenticated user has
  const subscriptionStatus = await checkExternalDatabase(username);

  // Stop Cognito flow based on subscription status 
  if (subscriptionStatus !== 'ACTIVE') {
    throw new Error('User does not have a valid subscription');
  }

  // Continue Cognito flow
  return event;
};
```

See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cognito-userpool.html#cfn-cognito-userpool-lambdaconfig